# JQuery Dialog and multi Mvc4 PartialView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

i have a View, and on a button click i need that open me a JQueryDialog loaded from PartialView that have inside a list of items... on click of one of these items, i need that in the same JQueryDialog open another PartialView, for editing this item, so a simple List/Detail nested in a JQueryDialog..

i post a sample..

http://sdrv.ms/15hG92K

VIEW

```
$('#dialogReferences').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: dWidth,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'TEST',
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        position: ['top', 100],
        open: function (event, ui)
        {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var url = '@Url.Action("ListItem", "Home")';

            $(this).dialog().load(url, function ()
            {
                $(document).unbind("click", ".k-grid-Edit").on("click", ".k-grid-Edit", function (evt)
                {
                    evt.preventDefault();

                    var grid = $("#contactsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                    var selectedData = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                    if (selectedData)
                    {
                        var urlEdit = '@(Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ItemEdit", "Home", new { selectedId = "_selectedId_" })))';
                        urlEdit = urlEdit.replace("_selectedId_", selectedData.Id);
                        $('#dialogReferences').dialog().load(urlEdit);
                    }
                });
                $(document).unbind("click", ".k-grid-Delete").on("click", ".k-grid-Delete", function (evt)
                {
                    evt.preventDefault();

                    var grid = $("#contactsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                    var selectedData = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                    if (selectedData)
                    {
                        var urlDelete = '@(Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ItemDelete", "Home", new { selectedId = "_selectedId_" })))';
                        urlDelete = urlDelete.replace("_selectedId_", selectedData.Id);


                        $.ajax({
                            url: urlDelete,
                            type: 'POST',
                            cache: false,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (result)
                            {
                                if (result.success)
                                {
                                    alert('DELETE');
                                    grid.dataSource.read();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

EDIT

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $(document).unbind("click","#btnCancel").one("click", "#btnCancel", function (evt)
    {
        evt.preventDefault();

        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        var urlList = '@Url.Action("ListItem", "Home")';

        $('#dialogReferences').dialog().load(urlList, function ()
        {
            $(document).unbind("click", ".k-grid-Edit").one("click", ".k-grid-Edit", function (evt)
            {
                evt.preventDefault();

                var grid = $("#contactsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                var selectedData = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                if (selectedData)
                {
                    var urlEdit = '@(Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ItemEdit", "Home", new { selectedId = "_selectedId_" })))';
                    urlEdit = urlEdit.replace("_selectedId_", selectedData.Id);
                    $('#dialogReferences').dialog().load(urlEdit);
                }
            });
            $(document).unbind("click", ".k-grid-Delete").on("click", ".k-grid-Delete", function (evt)
            {
                evt.preventDefault();

                var grid = $("#contactsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                var selectedData = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                if (selectedData)
                {
                    var urlDelete = '@(Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ItemDelete", "Home", new { selectedId = "_selectedId_" })))';
                    urlDelete = urlDelete.replace("_selectedId_", selectedData.Id);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: urlDelete,
                        type: 'POST',
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (result)
                        {
                            if (result.success)
                            {
                                alert('DELETE');
                                grid.dataSource.read();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    })
});
```

if i try to 'open file dialog' and delete without edit, it call delete action one time, and it's ok.
but if you try to enter in edit and than come back with cancel to the list, and delete, it call twice.

Someone can give me and advice?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — **in the question itself**.

Comment: i post some code, i hope is enough for explain my project